# Getting "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app." with navigation service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningnavigation, navigatetocomponent

I'm using below code to redirect to a lightning component.

```
          component.find("navService").navigate({
                "type": "standard__component",
                "attributes": {
                    "componentName": "c__CustomComponent"    
                },    
                "state": {
                    "c__myAttr": "attrValue"    
                }
            });
```

I have created a tab for that component also. But still getting error "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app."

It is showing URL as : https://mydomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__CustomComponent?c__myAttr=attrValue

Comment: Is the other component, where you want to redirect, implementing the correct interface : `implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable"` ? refer to the [documention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) for more details

Comment: I added it now, it is working.
Thank you.

Comment: Great. posted an answer, mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target component must implement the `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface to enable direct navigation via URL.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" description="target component">
    <aura:attribute name="myAttr" type="String" />
    <!-- additional code here -->
</aura:component>
```

More details from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)

Comment: How to handle above issue in LWC.? 
Is there any replacement for "lightning:isUrlAddressable" in LWC? @Shamina

Comment: @manoj If not already done, I suggest to post a new question for your query about LWC

Comment: @manoj - unfortunately, no, you cannot directly navigate to an LWC component. The standard workaround is to simply create a wrapper Aura component that contains the LWC, and then navigate to that Aura wrapper.